# Counting sort using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

another question about OpenMP...
I'm trying to speed up counting sort with OpenMP, but my code runs fastest on 1 thread, and slows down as I'm adding threads...(I've got 4 cores) Results are correct.
I'm paralleling only a loop in which the counter is incremented, the rest is computed sequentially (is that ok?) Here I try making incrementation by atomic operation. I tried also a version in which every thread had his own table "counters" but it was even slower.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) num_threads(4) default(none) shared(counters, table, possible_values, table_size)
    for(i=0; i < table_size; i++){
        #pragma omp atomic
        counters[(int)(table[i]*100)]++;

    }
```

table - contains unsorted values

possible_values - 100 (i've got numbers from 0 to 0.99)

table_size - size of table

How can I speed things up?

Comment: How large is table_size?, why are you sharing possible_values?

Comment: I tried different sizes, 10 000 for example

Comment: Only counters should be atomic, table doesn't have to be. 10000 is a relatively small number.

Comment: Now i tried to make simple for loop and it doesn't speed up either... Could you look at my another thread?

Comment: As suggested in the comments to your other question, you likely measure elapsed time incorrectly (though it's only a guess, since the time measurement code is not shown). Also, a loop of 10000 iterations each consisting of a few dozens of clockticks will definitely not benefit from parallelism; increase it by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Yes that was the case - I changed clock() to omp_get_wtime() and now its allright. Thanks!